# outdoor gfi stopped working

Tags: gfci, outdoor

I had an electrician come and change my outdoor outlet. He replaced it with a weatherproof GFI. It worked for 1 day and stopped working. I called him numerous times to come back but he would mot come. I got very frustrated and decided to see for my self what the problem was. It seems everything is fine as in the picture. My question is, from the picture is the wiring done properly ( I do not have any experience with this). IF yes I plane to purchase a new outlet and change it.[image]

Comment: just to clarify, the gfi is tripped and I cannot reset it, will not allow me reset.

Comment: Is there a hard use or in use cover on this? It looks like the cover screws one is broken off and the other has been drilled out. If water is getting into it from sprinklers or driven rain it could be the cause, with metal boxes I usually do tape the contacts, and there is a possibility of electronics failure with a new unit. Try turning the branch circuit breaker for a minute or 2 and see if it will reset.

Comment: A GFCI not receiving power will not reset.  I suspect there is another GFCI upstream that is tripped.

Comment: That was my next thought but figured the sparky would have checked...+

Comment: I suspect he wanted to sell a GFCI instead of an outlet and didn’t check the circuit at all.

Comment: The construction looks new enough that this location should have always been GFCI protected.  If it was a normal outlet before, there would be GFCI protection from another outlet or possibly the breaker. Rule this out, before proceeding.

Comment: You see that this GFCI is being used to feed other receptacles further on, BUT the way that it is connected at the line terminals only, means that the next receptacle in line will have power even if this GFCI is tripped.  Check another receptacle or a light fixture on this circuit to see if it has power. If it does not have power, that means that this GFCI is NOT getting power so there is nothing wrong with it. As people here have suggested, either you have another GFCI upstream of it which is tripped or the breaker is tripped. Is the breaker in the panel tripped? No? Look for another GFCI.

Comment: Look inside the house near this location and see if there is a GFCI receptacle there. If so, it is probably connected so as to supply GFCI protection to this location and all the outlets further on. If so, you only need a standard receptacle at this location. Oftentimes this is done so that the expensive GFCI is inside dry and protected from the weather, ants, and sprinklers.

Answer (score 4):

From the wiring, it looks like the power comes from some location upstream (toward the electrical panel) and then also carries power downstream (to other receptacles - outside ones)?   That is fairly normal for most receptacles, this is "chain style" wiring.

Now, GFCIs have both `LINE` and `LOAD` terminals which do different things.  There is a piece of tape across the `LOAD` terminals saying (in as many words) "DO NOT USE. For wizards only."  Your electrican heeded that advice. All wires are on the `LINE` side.

Now an electrician *should* be a wizard, but not all are, and also there are sometimes good reasons for not protecting downline loads.  For instance there may be faulty wiring or appliance downstream that was causing the GFCI to trip, so he chose not to protect the downstream part.

He also used a quality GFCI that used ["screw-and-clamp" type terminals](https://www.handymanhowto.com/electrical-outlets-side-wire-versus-back-wire/), which allow 2 wires to go on one screw.  If you buy *regular* receptacles, buy this kind - they are quite convenient and cost about $3 each (instead of 60 cents - no big).

Let's go back to the "chain" concept where receptacles are usually fed in a chain starting at the service panel.  (A "tree" layout is also perfectly fine, where power splits off in 2+ directions.)   Somewhere there'll be a receptacle *before this one* - i.e. one step closer to the panel.  Or not.  And another, or not. Etc.  All the way back to the panel.

It's very likely your problem is actually in one of those. It's likely you'll find a loose wire.  If you read that link about backstabs vs. screw-and-clamp, you'll know how to spot a backstab.  Those are troublesome, so I replace them on sight. Twist the wire out gently but persistently, no need to cut and lose length.

I don't like leaving nice things out in the rain. With GFCIs outdoors, I prefer to find (or create) a receptacle location *indoors*, fit the GFCI *there*, and use "wizard" skills and the `LOAD` screws to protect all the outdoor receptacles.